# Using gamm4 on zero-inflated count data with Tweedie or zero-inflated Poisson distributions

Tags: r, zero-inflation, gamm4

I'm working with a dataset with a large number of zero-counts on the response variable. This dataset consists of qualitatively coded interviews in a number of important categories, but many of the interviews don't contain information about the categories (hence, the zero-inflation). Here is a general description of some of the variables:

time: number of days since the start of data collection (numerical)
party: political party of the interviewee (factor)
network: news network the interview aired on (factor)
code: count data of the number of times the code is mentioned in a given interview (numerical) - this is the zero-inflated response variable
name: the individual politician who gave the interview (factor, used in the random effect nested within party)

Here is a histogram of one of the codes I'm interested in modeling.

[image]

I've been trying to model this data using a Tweedie distribution (which I've been told is more robust than Poisson or negative binomial distributions) or a zero-inflated Poisson distribution, but both are resulting in error messages in my code.

Here is some of my code:

```
real.mod.p <- gamm4(code ~ party + s(time, by=party, k=20),
         random =~ (1 | name/party),
         data=dat,
         family=tw)
```

I have no problems running this model with the gaussian family or the Poisson family, but when I switch the family to tw I get the following error message:

Error in as(value, fieldClass, strict = FALSE) : 
  internal problem in as(): “extended.family” is(object, "family") is TRUE, but the metadata asserts that the 'is' relation is FALSE

Similarly, when I switch the family to be a zero-inflated Poisson model using the following code:

```
real.mod.p <- gamm4(code ~ party + s(time, by=party, k=20),
         random =~ (1 | name/party),
         data=dat,
         family=ziplss)
```

I get this error message:

Error in eval(family$initialize, rho) : object 'E' not found

Is there a way to remedy these error messages so I can use one of these families to analyze my data? Is there a better family I should be using for this zero-inflated data? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use these extended families outside of `gam()` or `bam()` from the *mgcv* package.

With *gamm4* you're stuck with the families that `lmer()` and `glmer()` from the *lme4* package supports.

Options would be to use the *gamlss* package for ZIP models as I don't think it has a Tweedie family, or use the *glmmTMB* package which has lots of options, including `tw()` for a Tweedie family, however I don't believe it understands smooths so you'd need to convert your model into a form that can be fitted as a mixed effects model.

Another option, which is likely to be inefficient but which you can use to get started with immediately is to use the `"re"` basis spline with `gam()` or `bam()` and create a factor or `name` nested in `party` to use as the random effect, or even just `s(name, party, bs = 're')` might do it, assuming both are factors, but do the help for this basis to make sure I'm interpreting what you intend for the random effect.